# WCF+ timer. A bad practice?

Tags: c#, wcf, timer, communication

I would like for my service to be able to initiate communication with other services.

In order for it to act like a client and start the communication, I thought that an initialized in the constructor timer that calls a method every x seconds could be a good idea.

Is it a bad idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see what could be wrong with this approach.

You could utilize **System.Timers.Timer** - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Set its **Interval** to value at which you want to raise **Elapsed** event of timer. Subscribe to **Elapsed** event using an event handler which you implement, in which you would communicate with the external service.

Edit: simple example

```
 class Program
    {
        private static void timer_ElapsedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // communicate to external service
            Console.WriteLine("ElapsedEventHandler fired");
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            timer.Interval = 3000;
            timer.Elapsed += timer_ElapsedEventHandler;
            timer.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Timer started");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey thanks! I'll wait to see if i get more responses and mark your response as the answer. Btw the link you gave is in polish! Here is the english ver https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Yeah sorry for the link. Updated it. Good luck :)

Comment: By the way you initialized `timer` and not `DispatcherTimer`, i read it's not the same because of the thread they run. In my case there is no form so `DispatcherTimer` is the correct?

Comment: I have initialized DispatcherTimer from System.Windows.Threading namespace. Dispatcher timer is not limited to a single thread, which means each thread has its own dispatcher. The event is fired on the same thread as the dispatcher. If you want your operation to be ran on a separate thread then you should use System.Threading.Timer or System.Timers.Timer. The two Timers I just mentioned are very similar, the main difference is SynchronizationObject property of System.Timers.Timer, however I do not belive it does affect your case.

Comment: I just saw the `new DispatcherTimer();`. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, i'm atm trying to implement the timer but the called method get never called.

Comment: Make sure you have actually started the timer using Start() method. Have you tried debugging?

Comment: I even tried it in a console app and it didn't work... I switched to timers.timer and it works.

Comment: I will check it later at home and let you know what could be possibly wrong, currently I'm at work so can't. Anyway, its functionallty is pretty straightforward so it's weird that it's not working for you. Even the msdn example is simple.

Comment: Holy moly! I have investigated it and DispatcherTimer can't work properly from the Main method of console application, because when execution of Main method finishes - its process is ended because there are no other threads running in the background for the application (as I mentioned in one of above comments - DispatcherTimer's events are fired on the same thread as its instance "lives"). Sorry for misleading you. I have updated my answer. I wish I had actually thought of that when writing that comment...